When Calling google.cloud.automl.v1.AutoMl.GetModel from Crowdin
Title: Error When Calling google.cloud.automl.v1.AutoMl.GetModel from Crowdin
Body:
I'm encountering an issue when trying to call the google.cloud.automl.v1.AutoMl.GetModel method in the Google Cloud AutoML API from Crowdin. The method always returns 100%, and I'm not sure why this is happening.
Steps I've Tried:
Regenerated the API key (JSON).
Confirmed that the role is set to "Owner".
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this problem?
Regenerated the API key (JSON).
Confirmed that the role is set to "Owner".
I expected the GetModel method to return the model information as specified in the API documentation. However, every time I make the call from crowdin, it consistently returns a 100% completion status without providing the expected model details.
Actual Result:
The method returns 100% completion status without any further information, making it difficult to understand whether the model retrieval was successful or if there's an underlying issue.
